# Unable to locate package openvas - Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux

I've been trying to install OpenVas on my Kali Linux

[image]

I have no luck.

I tried to Google, I found this link

https://iamjagjeetubhi.wordpress.com/2017/04/10/fix-unable-to-locate-package-error-in-kali-linux/

I open that `sources.list`, and add these as suggested.

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
# For source package access, uncomment the following line
# deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
deb http://http.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates main contrib non-free
# For source package access, uncomment the following line
# deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib
# deb-src http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://old.kali.org/kali moto main non-free contrib
# For source package access, uncomment the following line
# deb-src http://old.kali.org/kali moto main non-free contrib
```

I ran the update, and see a lot of errors

```
root@kali:/etc/apt# apt-get update
Err:1 http://old.kali.org/kali moto InRelease
  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 54.39.49.227 80]
Err:2 http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates InRelease
  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
Err:3 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease                                                                      
  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]                                                                          
Err:4 http://http.kali.org/kali sana InRelease                                                                              
  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]                                                                          
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                               
W: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/InRelease  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 192.99.200.113 80] 
W: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/sana/InRelease  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]         
W: Failed to fetch http://security.kali.org/kali-security/dists/sana/updates/InRelease  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]                                                                                                                
W: Failed to fetch http://old.kali.org/kali/dists/moto/InRelease  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 54.39.49.227 80]            
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.                                   
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:7 and /etc/apt/sources.list:17                                                                                                                    
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:7 and /etc/apt/sources.list:17                                                                                                                      
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:7 and /etc/apt/sources.list:17                                                                                                               
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:7 and /etc/apt/sources.list:17                                                                                                                  
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:7 and /etc/apt/sources.list:17
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:7 and /etc/apt/sources.list:17
W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:7 and /etc/apt/sources.list:17
W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:7 and /etc/apt/sources.list:17
W: Target Packages (non-free/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:7 and /etc/apt/sources.list:17
W: Target Packages (non-free/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:7 and /etc/apt/sources.list:17
W: Target Translations (non-free/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:7 and /etc/apt/sources.list:17
W: Target Translations (non-free/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:7 and /etc/apt/sources.list:17
```

Can someone please help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got several warning messages that packages are configured multiple times in `/etc/apt/sources.list`

1. `sudoedit` opens nano editor in the terminal by default in Kali Linux. Open `/etc/apt/sources.list` for editing in nano editor:

   ```
   sudoedit /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```
2. Comment out the 4 new lines that you added to sources.list by preceding each of the 4 new lines with a `#` character.

   ```
   deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free  
   deb http://http.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib  
   deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates main contrib non-free  
   deb http://old.kali.org/kali moto main non-free contrib
   ```
3. Find all remaining duplicate lines, and comment them out by preceding each duplicate line with a `#` character. Don't comment out both duplicate lines, just comment out one of the two duplicate lines to remove the warning message.
4. Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the sources.list file to its current location. Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.
5. Enable the changes in sources.list by updating the list of available software.

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```

---

*openvas* is a metapackage that installs a few Debian packages along with itself. To install all these packages open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install greenbone-security-assistant openvas-cli openvas-manager openvas-scanner rsync sqlite3 xsltproc
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and ran it. I got this error now : https://i.imgur.com/CBB9vMA.png

Comment: [source:](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/) The single most common causes of a broken Kali Linux installation are following unofficial advice, and particularly arbitrarily populating the system’s sources.list file with unofficial repositories. The following post aims to clarify what repositories should exist in sources.list, and when they should be used. Any additional repositories added to the Kali sources.list file will most likely BREAK YOUR KALI LINUX INSTALL. (That's what you did.)

Comment: The error is occurring because you're mixing multiple releases in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Run the command `cat /etc/lsb-release` to show what version (*DISTRIB_CODENAME*) of Kali Linux you are running and comment out all lines from other versions from `/etc/apt/sources.list` by preceding each of these lines with a # character. Then run `sudo apt update`